# Kendall's Notation for Kelly Networks?

Tags: notation, definition, queueing, kelly-network, kendall-notation

## Background

[Kendall's notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall%27s_notation) (also see [Ciw docs'](https://ciw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Background/kendall.html)) is a convenience when you work with queues a lot. It not only provides an abbreviation, but its wide use helps make literature searches more specific.

AFAIK Kendall's notation is used to describe a single queue, but what if I have a network of different queues that behave differently depending on the customer?

## Question

How do I denote Kelly networks where the nodes are possibly distinct in their queueing description?

## Attempted Answer

Things just get too complicated once you get into networks. There often will be no added benefit to human readability to have some specialized notation for an entire network **over** having good diagrams. For machines you can automatically store complex models in data structures or serialize them as needed. So draw good pictures for your fellow humans (and yourself).

---

## Example:

Take this example from the [Ciw documentation](https://ciw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial-II/tutorial_vii.html):

```py
import ciw

N = ciw.create_network(
    arrival_distributions={
        'Baby': [ciw.dists.Exponential(rate=1.0),
                 None,
                 None],
        'Child': [ciw.dists.Exponential(rate=2.0),
                  None,
                  None]
    },
    service_distributions={
        'Baby': [ciw.dists.Exponential(rate=4.0),
                 ciw.dists.Exponential(rate=1.0),
                 ciw.dists.Deterministic(value=0.0)],
        'Child': [ciw.dists.Exponential(rate=6.0),
                  ciw.dists.Deterministic(value=0.0),
                  ciw.dists.Exponential(rate=1.0)]
    },
    routing={'Baby': [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
             'Child': [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
    },
    number_of_servers=[1, 2, 3],
)
```

The documentation explains the example above in more detail. I also wrote [*An Overview of Ciw*](https://galenseilis.github.io/posts/overview-ciw/) if you want some more information about Ciw beyond the documentation.

There are only three nodes, but they have different rules around their arrival distributions, service distributions, and routing depending on whether the customer is a baby or a child. But basically, the system is a [Kelly network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_network) because there is more than one class of customer. I like this example because it typifies how I find Kendall's notation to be incomplete (at least in my understanding of it).

Comment: Disclosure: I am a [contributor to Ciw](https://ciw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Reference/authors.html).